# springboot gives error "Could not find or load main class" if we add add "spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server" dependency using maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

when i run the spring-boot application without Eureka server its successfully run but when i add the Eureka server dependancy in the pom.xml file using maven then its give error ##Error: Could not find or load main class io.javabrains.discoveryserver.DiscoveryServerApplication##

i tried with different version of eureka server and updating maven but did not work

```
pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.javabrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>discovery-server</name>
    <description>Discovery Server shafaqat</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR3</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Main Java file

```
package io.javabrains.discoveryserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}




i expect to run this application using successfully for the Eureka server.
```

Comment: Can you post complete pom file?

Comment: Did you also add `<dependencyManagement>` into your `pom.xml` just like the official tutorial [Service Registration and Discovery](https://spring.io/guides/gs/service-registration-and-discovery/).

Comment: @LHCHIN Yes I have added  the `<dependencyManagement>`

Comment: @NirajJha  I have added the pom.xml file

Comment: Now its showing the different error
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.api.core.DefaultResourceConfig
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
 ... 25 common frames omitted`

Comment: can yo replace the dependency with this one 

<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId> </dependency>